# Switching Between GCS & PCS in a Data Frame For Accurate Acreage/Distance Measurements

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, data-frame

I'm working with a data frame that contains multiple layers; data frame and layers all use a GCS (WGS_1984).  On one layer in particular, I want to be able to draw and measure the acreage of polygons.  I know I can't measure acreage in a GCS, I would need to use a Projected coordinate system.
What would be my solution?  Project the desired .shp file into a PCS and then do a data frame transformation into the same PCS...?  Is the project on the fly function alone enough to allow me to be able to accurately measure acreage and distance off of a GCS layer in a PCS data frame?

[I'm working at a VERY close-up scale, mapping out crop plantings at the feet/inches level, on a small city/county (Kauai, HI) scale. I'm using the NAD_1983_HARN Hawaii state plane for my PCS when applicable.]

Comment: Use an equal-area projected coordinate system when you want to measure area accurately. Use an equal-distance projected coordinate system to measure distance accurately. If you're mapping at a very close-up scale (eg on the scale of a city, county, or small state), use the local (state plane if in the USA) coordinate system for area *and* distance.

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to contain these details.